# Problems running/configure self hosted console application (ASP.net core 2.1, Kestrel) with public certificate on a windows webserver

Tags: https, asp.net-core-mvc, certificate, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I have developed various webservices in the past (VB ASP.net web-api applications) with https for production.
I have done the development with http and then setup https on the production servers.
**To setup a port on the production server for https and the certificate, I have:**

1. Imported a public certificate in the certificate store on the
   windows    server configured a specific port for https with netsh.
   E.g:

> netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:22224/ user=everyone

2. bound the certificate (over the thumbprint) to the port. E.g:

> netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:22224
>   certhash=31cf73308a768100d4d32fe6e77638593e68ab57
>   appid={a33a711f-c587-44e5-96bc-dca8a7f3fc3c}

3. Setup the application to listen to the specific port, whereby I have
   read the url from a config file at startup - e.g. https://IP:Port and applied
   it to (vb.net) HttpSelfHostConfiguration()

This works without problems and I am able to configure the applications as I need it (e.g. configure a port in the config file for http for doing tests on a intranet server, configure another port in the config file for the production environment with https).

Now, I want to do the same with an **asp.net core 2.1.6** application and **it seems not to work the same way.**
Public certificate (comodo) is installed in the certificate store of the windows web server.
Port 22224 is configured with netsh for https.
The certificate is bound to the port with netsh (certificate is showed correct with netsh http show sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:22224
In **Program.cs**, I add the port to listen with UseUrls:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>() //;
            .UseUrls(GV.cURL, "http://localhost:5000"); 
    }
```

whereby GV.curl contains https://IP:22224 at runtime

The application run’s fine (over the Internet), if I configure it to a **http**-port (e.g. http://IP:22222).
If I set the (configured) https port (https://IP:22224), the application don’t start and give out the error message:
**Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. *No server certificate was specified*, and the default developer certificate could not be found.**

The information’s, I found on the web are confusing and it seems as this theme is a “moving target” (often changes in the base handling of asp.net core x-x).
**My findings for now:**
The snipped “***No server certificate was specified***” in the error message indicates, that the certificate **has to be configured in the application?**

I have found **an example** to specify a certificate in CreateWebHostBuilder with .useKestrel options:

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "topsecret");
            });
```

Note: In my case, I would have to change 5001 to 22224.

**Questions:**

- **Do I really have to configure the (already to the port bound) public 
  certificate also in the asp.net core 2.1 application?**
- **If yes, what is the best way to do this (is the example above a good way)?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of try-and-error, I have found the relevant information that works for me.
Note: I work with **ASP.net core 2.1.6** now (if you work with an older version, this may not work for you...

You **don’t need** to do any configuration with netsh, but you have to configure the cert (including password).
You further not need to change the program.cs...
The configurations can be done completely in **appsettings.json (included in the project root)**
So... in the project (debugging on my machine), I work with the default appsettings.json (with http):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

On the **intranet** server, I use another appsettings.json (still with http):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
,
    "Kestrel": {
      "EndPoints": {
        "Http1": { "Url": "http://localhost:5000" },
        "Http2": { "Url": "http://172.16.1.120:22222" }
        }
      }
    }
```

This way, the app can be tested in the LAN over the IP address of the intranet server and also directly on the intranet server (localhost port 5000).

On the **internet** server, I use another appsettings.json (for localhost with http, **for the server IP with https and certficate**):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
,
    "Kestrel": {
        "EndPoints": {
            "Http": {
                "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
            },
            "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
                "Url": "https://192.168.3.3:22224",
                "Certificate": {
                    "Path": "./certificate.pfx",
                    "Password": "NotReally",
                    "AllowInvalid": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the app can be tested with http directly on the intranet server and with https and cert over the internet.

**Handling:**

- On the servers, I have a root directory for the application.
- Directly under the root, I have stored copies of the "per machine" different files (including appsettings.json)
- To publish a new version, I publish on my dev machine and then copy the \publish\ directory to the servers (under the root directory) and overwrite the stored files.
- To have the correct config, I have created a simple **.cmd**, that copies the (server specific) config files from the root in the subdirectory \publish\ that I run after a fresh publish...

**Notes to https and the certificate:**

- The certificate has to be stored in the \publish\ folder.
- As the (my) public contoso certificate does secure a few domains, https only works properly, if the app is called over the domain (else, the good knowing “not secure” messages are showed).
- To be able to test the app with https, I have opened the port 22224 on the windows- and the “real” firewall.
- The DNS points to the public IP of our internet server.
  For testing, I call the App with https://www.Domain.xx:22224

And... it works...

Comment: Good point: "The certificate has to be stored in the \publish\ folder."

Answer (score 6):

I am using a Dockerized deployment for my ASP.Net Core App v2.2 and have used the following guides to make it work (this [should work as of v2.1, Jan. 2017](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1290#issuecomment-353416087)):

- This Stackoverflow question:
  [Configure ASP.NET Core 2.0 Kestrel for HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336341/configure-asp-net-core-2-0-kestrel-for-https)
- [This is a useful article](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core) which goes through certificate creation, trusting it on different machines and configuring the .Net Project (v2.0).

What I basically did was:

- Store the certificate (in this example for *localhost* development) in a certificates folder:
  [image]
- appsettings.json:

```
    "Kestrel": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5051;http://localhost:5050",
      "Certificates": {
        "Default": {
          "Path": "certificates/localhost.pfx",
          "Password": "MySecret",
          "AllowInvalid": "true"
        }
      }
    }
```

- Set the application URLs

  - via launchsettings.json (only local development)

```
    "kamapp-backend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5051;http://localhost:5050",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
```

- via environment `ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:5050;https://+:5051"`,  eg. `ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+:5050;https://+:5051" dotnet run`

  - You don't have to code any settings, just use the config files.

Forcing HTTPS:
`app.UseHsts();` in your Startup.cs

It also seems to work without the `"AllowInvalid": "true"`, but I don't understand why yet. Maybe someone can answer.

Comment: Compare with [this article](https://www.humankode.com/asp-net-core/develop-locally-with-https-self-signed-certificates-and-asp-net-core); it seems we have a choice, do it in configuration or use the middleware pipeline builder.

Answer (score 1):

i solve this issue just run two commend in cmd

1. run the cmd
2. enter the commend `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
3. finally enter the command `dotnet dev-certs https -t`
4. get the message "The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully."
5. run the .net core project

Answer (score -3):

for development environment i use the below appsettings.json

Here i am not using https, i used http.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "http": { "Url": "http://localhost:5000" }
    }
  }
}
```